# How to have different Cloud Functions files for different firebase user accounts

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a lot of Cloud Functions I use for work in a file. I'm wondering how I could have another set of Cloud Functions stored in a different place and then upload them to a different project. I know that I can switch the project by doing, `firebase use (name)`, but I'm not sure how to specify which file to upload.

When I deploy it only seems to take what is in `/Users/{username}/functions`

In short: I would like a directory that uploads to project1, and a different directory that uploads to project2

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're trying to accomplish.  Are you saying that you want to be able to deploy two different sets of functions to the same project, being able to switch easily between them?  Or are you working with multiple projects?  Please edit your question to be more specific.  Also, FYI, everything under `functions` is always deployed every time - you can't change that.

Comment: @DougStevenson I have two different projects, and I'm hoping to have two different directories so that the second project doesn't get the functions of the first and vice versa. Basically directory 1 -> project 1 when deployed. directory 2 -> project 2 when deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run `firebase init` in a new folder, part of the process is attaching it to a Firebase project.  You can easily have any number of project workspace folders attached to any number of projects.  I personally have dozens of folders attached to dozens of projects across three accounts.  You can tell which project an folder is attached to by looking at the `.firebaserc` file in that folder.  It will contain something like this:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "your-project-id"
  }
}
```

When you run `firebase deploy` from there, it will go to the current account's project with the id `your-project-id`.

The key thing to remember with the Firebase CLI with multiple Google account is this: it can only be logged into one Google account at a time.  So if you're trying to manage multiple projects across multiple accounts, you have to `firebase logout` followed by `firebase login` with an active browser window logged into the account you want to switch to.

Comment: Just to add, it turns out my issue was that I had previously done firebase init in my Users directory. The problem with creating new projects was that it tried to always create them their because apparently it checks all roots of for a firebase.json file. Moving that project into its own folder fixed the issue.